# Specific font for a specific encoding or language

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, cyrillic, substitution, garamondx

Is there a way to specify a specific font for a specific encoding or language?

Using the default font for everything has proper shapes, but using `garamondx` has no proper shapes for cyrillic, even when not using my hack. Is the problem that `garamondx` lacks cyrillic or that its package does not deal with that lack gracefully?

[image: MWE PDF output]

Note: the MWE requires `garamondx` and `literaturnaya` from the [TUG getnonfreefonts script](http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts). (It might be the same with other fonts.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,american]{babel}
\usepackage{garamondx}

%%% The hack
\DeclareFontSubstitution{T2A}{tli}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

This should be Garamond.

The following should be Literaturnaya:

\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}

\textbf{Русский язык} \ensuremath{\leftarrow} (should be bold)

\emph{восточнославянских} \ensuremath{\leftarrow} (should be italic)

\emph{\textbf{русского народа}} \ensuremath{\leftarrow} (should be bold italic).

\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a job for `\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,american]{babel}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{\rmdefault}{tli}%
} % some packages could set \rmdefault at begin document

\begin{document}

This should be Garamond.

The following should be Literaturnaya:

\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}

\textbf{Русский язык} \ensuremath{\leftarrow} (should be bold)

\emph{восточнославянских} \ensuremath{\leftarrow} (should be italic)

\emph{\textbf{русского народа}} \ensuremath{\leftarrow} (should be bold italic).

\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With some black magic that shows the current font, just for being completely sure we get the expected one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian,american]{babel}
\usepackage{garamondx}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{\rmdefault}{tli}%
} % some packages could set \rmdefault at begin document

    \newcommand{\?}{%
      \space
      \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
        {%
         \noexpand\ttfamily\noexpand\upshape
         \noexpand\string\the\font=\fontname\font
        }%
      }\x
    }

\begin{document}

This should be Garamond.

The following should be Literaturnaya:

\begin{otherlanguage}{russian}

\textbf{Русский язык\?}

\emph{восточнославянских\?}

\emph{\textbf{русского народа}\?}

\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: see edit history for a previous solution using the `substitutefont` package, now declared obsolete.

Comment: This works until I add the `garamondx` option `osfI` for old style figures. What could be causing this, and is that better suited to a new question?

Comment: @svenper Fixed. The `osfI` option causes `\rmdefault` to be set at begin document rather than in the preamble.